# RWD catalog tab css problem

Tags: category, template, custom, rwd, zoom

I have a RWD catelog template css problem.
see here [image]

Thanks!

---

I found this to be chrome problem, the problem has not been solved yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a smaller value for the `z-index` of the "Description" tab.